# Кривой скрипт отправки сообщения

Tags: php

Приветствую, уважаемые гуру.
Для меня задача оказалась непосильна, поэтому обращаюсь к вам за помощью. 
Есть определенный код, глядя на который в принципе понятно, что он делает и как, но к сожалению, код достался мне в непотребном виде. Начальство стоит уже над душой, а я админ, я не программист, но решать проблему больше некому, ибо человек, писавший сие недоступен никаким средствам связи. Решить надо вчера, а я только неделю назад начал PHP изучать... короче, прошу вашей помощи, веря, что человеку с опытом будет с первого взгляда понятно, в чем конкретно косяки. Тут могут быть и кривые кавычки и прочей фигни. И вещей а ля "а зачем оно тут?". К сожалению опыта моего не хватает.
З.Ы. автор сего творения писал код в каком-то непонятном редакторе, ибо кавычки все были вида » и смотрели в одну сторону - пришлось заменять.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$post = (!empty ($_POST)) ? true : false;
if ($post) {
  $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
  $email = trim($_POST['email']);
  $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
  $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
  $error = »;
// Check name
  if (!$name) {
    $error = 'Please enter your name.<br />';
  }
// Check email
  function ValidateEmail($value) {
    $regex = '/^([w-]+(?:.[w-]+)*)@((?:[w-]+.)*w[w-]{0,66}).([a-z]{2,6}(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$/i';
    if ($value == » ) {
      return false;
    }
    else {
      $string = preg_replace($regex, » , $value);
    }
    return empty ($string) ? true : false;
  }
  if (!$email) {
    $error = 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
  }
  if ($email && !ValidateEmail($email)) {
    $error = "Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />";
  }
// Check message (length)
  if (!$message || strlen($message) < 15) {
    $error = 'Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.<br />';
  }
  if (!$error) {
    $mail = mail(mail@host.ru, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">rn" . "Reply-To: " . $email . "rn" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());
    if ($mail) {
      echo 'OK';
    }
  }
  else {
    echo '<div class="notification_error">' . $error . '</div>';
  }
}
?>
```

Данный код по идее, на сколько я понял должен получать переменные методом POST от JS скрипта на сайте.
Пример того как не работает - вместо текста ошибки($error) выдает вот этот кусок кода

```
'; } // Check email function ValidateEmail($value) { $regex = '/^([w-]+(?:.[w-]+)*)@((?:[w-]+.)*w[w-]{0,66}).([a-z]{2,6}(?:.[a-z]{2})?)$/i'; if ($value == "") { return false; } else { $string = preg_replace($regex, "", $value); } return empty ($string) ? true : false; } if (!$email) { $error = 'Please enter an e-mail address.
'; } if ($email && !ValidateEmail($email)) { $error = "Please enter a valid e-mail address.
"; } // Check message (length) if (!$message || strlen($message) < 15) { $error = 'Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.
'; } if (!$error) { $mail = mail(kirill@hasanoff.ru, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name . " <" . $email . ">rn" . "Reply-To: " . $email . "rn" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()); if ($mail) { echo 'OK'; } } else { echo '
' . $error . '
```

в том месте, где должен появляется текст ошибки.
Заранее благодарен за помощь в моих идиотских вопросах.

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж стал придираться к "правкам" [[@VenZell](/users/13336/venzell)](/users/13336/venzell), то укажу и свой вариант "исправленного" скрипта. Замечу, что число строк не изменилось, зато появилась примитивная конфигурация и убраны все ошибки логики. С другой стороны, судя по `<br>` в конце сообщений об ошибках подозреваю, что ошибки должны были выдаваться скопом, а не последовательно, как в моем варианте, но возврат к той логике вывода ошибок при таком коде достаточно очевиден и прост.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    $min_message_length = 15;
    $mail_to = "mail@host.ru";

    $mail_headers = array();
    $mail_headers[] = 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $name = '';
    $email = '';
    $subject = '';
    $message = '';

    foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue)
    {
        if (is_string($varvalue)) {
            $$varname = htmlspecialchars(trim($varvalue));
        }
    }

    if (!$name) {
        error('Please enter your name.');
    }

    if (!testMail($email)) {
        error('Please enter a valid e-mail address.');
    }

    if (strlen($message) < $min_message_length) {
        error('Please enter your message. It should have at least ' . $min_message_length . ' characters.');
    }

    $mail_headers[] = 'From: ' . $name . '<' . $email . '>';

    $headers = implode("\n", $mail_headers);

    if (mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        die('OK');
    }
    else {
        error('Error send.');
    }

    function error($text)
    {
        die('<div class="notification_error">' . $text . '</div>');
    }

    function testMail($mail)
    {
        return preg_match('|([a-z0-9_\.\-]{1,20})@([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,20})\.([a-z]{2,4})|is', $mail);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай **сохраните исходный вариант** вашего скрипта. Изучив его поподробнее, понял, что проще будет его переписать, чем указывать на ошибки.
Основная проблема была в регулярном выражении, которое не захватывало e-mail и путанице в возвращаемых функцией проверки e-mail'а значениях.
Вот рабочий вариант скрипта (проверил на локальном сервере, письмо уходит как положено):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$min_message_length = 15;
$mail_to = "mail@host.ru";

if (!empty ($_POST)) {
    $name = checkVariable($_POST['name']);
    $email = checkVariable($_POST['email']);
    $subject = checkVariable($_POST['subject']);
    $message = checkVariable($_POST['message']);
    $error = "";

// Check name
    if (!$name) {
        $error .= "Please enter your name." . "<br />";
    }

// Check email
    if (!$email || !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error .= "Please enter a valid e-mail address." . "<br />";
    }

// Check message (length)
    if (!$message || strlen($message) < $min_message_length) {
        $error .= "Please enter your message." . " " .
            "It should have at least {$min_message_length} characters." . "<br />";
    }

// Sending message
    if (!$error) {
        $mail_headers = "From: {$name} <{$email}>" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: {$email}" . "\r\n" .
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $mail = mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $mail_headers);
        if ($mail) {
            echo "OK";
        } else {
            echo "Your message wasn't sent";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<div class='notification_error'>" . $error . "</div>";
    }
}

function checkVariable($var)
{
    if (!empty($var) && is_string($var)) {
        return htmlspecialchars(trim($var));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил, но проблема, к сожалению осталась.

Comment: Переписал скрипт. Попробуйте этот вариант.

Comment: Забавно звучит это Ваше "переписал". Ну раз уж начали исправлять приведенный код - так исправили бы всё от и до, а не только одну строчку логики.

Comment: Да, Вы совершенно правы. Пропустил еще пару ошибок. В частности, неверные разделители строк в заголовках письма.  
Причесал код, заменил "велосипед" встроенной функцией, исправил ошибки. Теперь, вроде бы, все. Спасибо, что не прошли мимо и ткнули носом в халтуру.

Comment: "Халтуры" еще много осталось...) Кто сказал, что ключи `name`, `email`, `subject`, `message` у `$_POST` существуют? Кто сказал, что они строки, а не массивы? А ведь мы сами указали, что хотим видеть в том числе и `E_NOTICE`, а `trim` и `stripslashes` генерируют как раз `E_NOTICE` если на входе массив. `stripslashes` нужен лишь при включенной директиве `magic_quotes_gpc`, а ведь мы современные люди и знаем, что с PHP 5.3 этой директивы больше нет. Ну а в остальном - да, исправились. Но "читабельнее" не стало...)

Comment: З.Ы. если будете еще править - поставьте заодно конкатенацию на `$error`, чтобы ошибки выводились все сразу - судя по всему такова была задумка автора.

Comment: Будем надеяться, что совместными усилиями доведем этот скрипт до ума. Написал функцию для проверки и очистки переменных $_POST + использовал вашу идею с конфигурацией. Если что-то еще пропустил, внесу правки утром. Еще раз спасибо.